# W-4 Second Job Question

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-w-4, covid-19

With the whole COVID-19 thing happening a lot of my financing and paper work on stuff is a little complicated right now. I'm also pretty inexperienced with this stuff because I've only ever held a single job before.

I'm currently applying for a second job because my first one is temporarily closed due to the closure of the facility. I've been applied to unemployment for about a month now because of the closure. While I haven't been accepted yet for the second job I was given some of the documents to fill out online. 
I'm a little confused on what I should put on my W-4 form for this job.

Should I consider it a second job or file it as my only job? If I do file it as my second job should I just pick the option in step 2 option (c) which states "If there is only two jobs total, you may check this box..." ?

Answer (score 7):

> Should I consider it a second job or file it as my only job?

Unless you will end up working two jobs at the same time. I would consider this new  as your only job.

If in a normal year a person starts the year working for company A, and then part of the way through the year switches to company B. They would complete the W-4 for Company B as if they only had one job.  If the two jobs had similar pay, then the combination of jobs and forms would be close enough. If the two jobs were very different in pay, there is a risk of under or over payment.

But this isn't a normal year. If you find that you end up working multiple jobs simultaneously, then I would review the W-4 forms submitted to see if the more detailed [IRS W4 estimator](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/tax-withholding-estimator) would be  helpful.

Comment: +1. And it’s worth noting that whatever you choose on your W-4 is not permanent. If you fill out the form and then later decide that more or less tax should be withheld from your paycheck, you can submit a new W-4 to your employer at any time.